# How to show org-habit graph alone?

Tags: org-mode, org-habit

When I'm writing my weekly review I want to see my habits in a way that tells me which habit I did and which I didn't in this week. 
Show the complete graph of habits may be enough for this, but how can I see this graph alone? If I opened my agenda I need to go to the next day to see the complete graph again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can display all habit graphs regardless of being due by setting `(set 'org-habit-show-all-today t)` or any non-nil value.

If you'd prefer to have your habits separated from the full agenda (or not see the full list outside weekly review) you can use a `todo-tags` view such as `("h" "Habits" tags-todo "STYLE=\"habit\"" ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Habits")))` and the code from which Aaron Harris posted [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13360/org-habit-graph-on-todo-list-agenda-view) to get habit graphs to show in tag and search views. Don't forget to change the variable `my/org-habit-show-graphs-everywhere` to non-nil on the first line. The comments there mention it but it's easy to miss.

Comment: I'm using `(set 'org-habit-show-all-today t)`... the options with `tags-todo` doesn't show th the graph, only list the entries.

Comment: Yep, you need some extra code to get the graph in non-agenda views, I linked to where you can find that code in the answer.  Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Unfortunately the Aaron Harris's code doesn't work for me... :(

Comment: Try it with my/org-habit-show-graphs-everywhere non-nil.

Comment: Thank you @Gooby it works! I don't know why call `tags-todo` with this type of search is incredible slow on my machine, but works at least.