# Org mode agenda fails to show consistency graph

Tags: org-mode

I set up the Org mode consistency graph of habits following [the manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-your-habits.html#Tracking-your-habits). Each habit is, e.g.:

```
** TODO some habit
SCHEDULED: <2019-12-22 Sun 07:20 ++1d>
:PROPERTIES:
:STYLE: habit
:LAST_REPEAT: [2019-12-21 Sat 09:14]
:END:
:LOGBOOK:
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2019-12-21 Sat 09:14]
...
:END:
```

and my init file has:

```lisp
;; track habits
(add-to-list 'org-modules 'habits)
(setq org-habit-graph-column 65)
(setq org-habit-show-habits-only-for-today nil)
```

The consistency graph showed in agenda view for the week yesterday and I cannot replicate it now, either in view for the week or the day. I tried adding the code from [How to show org-habit graph alone?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32010/how-to-show-org-habit-graph-alone)

```lisp
(set 'org-habit-show-all-today t)
```

Pressing `K` in either day or week view shows that the buffer is read-only in the mini-buffer.

How can I set up the consistency graph or debug what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using DEADLINE instead of SCHEDULED. I had the same problem and I solved it by using SCHEDULED.

Comment: I confirm that my habits all have `SCHEDULED` and not `DEADLINE`.