# How can I get a custom agenda habits only view with history chart?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-habit

I have included in my `org-agenda-custom-commands` the following:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(
    ...
    ("h" "Habits" tags-todo "STYLE=\"habit\""
     ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Habits")
      (org-agenda-sorting-stragety
       '(todo-state-down effort-up category-keep))))
    ...))
```

This properly displays all habit type todos I have in my agenda files regardless of their completion and due statuses. It doesn't show the history chart I see in agenda views since setting `org-habit-graph-column`.  How can I see that graph in this habit-only view?

Answer (score 1):

This has turned out to be roughly the same question as [org-habit graph on todo list agenda view](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13360/org-habit-graph-on-todo-list-agenda-view/13864#13864) where Aaron Harris provided an effective answer.